# Ambiguous type reference

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, multiple-inheritance

Why does this works :

```
template <typename T> 
struct foo
{
};

struct A
{
    typedef foo<A> type;
};

struct B : public A
{
    typedef foo<B> type;
};

int main()
{
    B::type john;
    return 0;
}
```

But not this :

```
template <typename T> 
struct foo
{
};

template <typename T>
struct Shared
{
    typedef foo<T> type;
};

struct A : public Shared<A>
{
};

struct B : public A, public Shared<B>
{
};

int main()
{
    // g++ 4.5 says :
    // error: reference to 'type' is ambiguous
    B::type john;
    return 0;
}
```

In my code, `foo` is actually `boost::shared_ptr` and, as you can see, I'm trying so factor some `typedef`s using a `Shared` class.

Comment: Because, which B::type are you refering to, B::A::Shared<A>::type or B::Shared<B>::type, they're not the same...  In you're first example, you're specifying which type you're talking about, since it's actually defined in the B class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `B` inherits `foo<B>` and, indirectly, `foo<A>`, and both contain a member `type`. Which did you mean?

Your simple, first piece of code has `B`'s `type` *hiding* `A`'s `type`, but that doesn't happen in the more complex second piece of code, which involves a deeper inheritance tree.

Answer (score 1):

Because you actually have 2 `type` typedefs. One from `A`, which gets his from `shared<A>` and one from `shared<B>`. In your first case, you hide the `type` typedef of the `A` base class with the typedef in `B`.