# C++: How to prevent private names from polluting derived types?

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, radix, ambiguity

I was shocked today by the fact that this code snippet has an ambiguous name reference:

```cpp
class A
{
private:
    typedef int Type;
};

class B
{
public:
    typedef int Type;
};

class D : A, B
{
    Type value;//error: reference to 'Type' is ambiguous
};
```

Hmm! Imagine you are the author of class `A` and your class has already been used everywhere by different people and different projects. One day you decide to rewrite your `A` class. Doesn't this mean that you cannot use any new (even private) name in your new class without breaking others' code?

What is the convention here?

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5445299/1025391 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/37206557/1025391

Comment: pimpl idiom, so you no longer have to change private interface.

Comment: The semantic meaning of C++ programs is not affected by `public/private` declarations. But the *legality* of them is. If it compiled the first time, changing `private` to `public` should not break it.

Answer (score 2):

*Yes you are right*. Using the current format/logic/coding style might break others' code if you decide to make changes later.
Try to use PIMPL or fully qualify symbols.
You're example is a good one of why it's not a good idea to not use fully qualify symbols.
It's the same issue with code like:

```
using namespace std;
```

The line of code above could break a lot of stuff.

Comment: @zwhconst can you mark the correct answear?

Answer (score 0):

As @Jarod42 mentioned it needs to follow [pimpl idiom](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/09/22/make-pimpl-using-unique_ptr/) (pointer to implementation) to separate interface and implementation:

**A.h**

```cpp
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:    
    A(); 
    ~A();     
private:
    class AImpl; 
    std::unique_ptr<AImpl> pimpl;
};
```

**A.cpp**

```cpp
#include "A.h"

class A::AImpl 
{
private:
    typedef int Type;

    /* .. */
};

A::A(): pimpl(new AImpl)
{
}

A::~A() = default;
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "A.h"

class B
{
public:
    typedef int Type;
};

class D : A, B
{
    Type value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no issue here, it's not because it's private that the symbol does not exists. If you try to access a private member the compiler tells you that you can't access it, not that does not exists.

Also, I would say it's a bad practise to use multiple inheritence and not fully qualify symbols.

```cpp
class D : A, B
{
    B::Type value;
};
```